# opacity and scale css3 animation not working in safari

Tags: css, safari, css-animations

Here is a jfiddle of it, it works in all browsers except safari, and I don't know why not, I have split it up in to shorthand.

http://jsfiddle.net/v7m713qm/2/

```
 -webkit-animation-name:anim-effect-glow;
  -webkit-animation-duration:1.5s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-out;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;


@-webkit-keyframes anim-effect-glow {
   0% {
     opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 1);
     transform: scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 1);

  }
  100% {
     opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
     transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your example is NOT working in ANY browser.

Comment: There was a bug earlier with animations on pseudo-element content like mentioned in this [CSS Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/transitions-and-animations-on-css-generated-content/). You may want to check if your browser version is supported.

Comment: my example works on firefox , chrome and opera at least

Comment: Well, what should happen then ? I've tried with both Firefox and Chrome... I can only see a blank area with cursor: pointer and nothing else. ?